# Match Multiline & IgnoreSome

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to extract some information from a JCL source using regex in C#
Basically, this is a string I can have:

```
//JOBNAME0 JOB (BLABLABLA),'SOME TEXT',MSGCLASS=YES,ILIKE=POTATOES, GRMBL
//             IALSOLIKE=TOMATOES,      ANOTHER GARBAGE
//             FINALLY=BYE
//OTHER STUFF
```

So I need to extract the jobname `JOBNAME0`, the info `(BLABLABLA)`, the description `'SOME TEXT'` and the other parms `MSGCLASS=YES` `ILIKE=POTATOES` `IALSOLIKE=TOMATOES` `FINALLY=BYE`.

I must ignore everything that is after the space ... like `GRMBL` or `ANOTHER GARBAGE`

I must continue to next line if my last valid char was a `,` and stop if it there were none.

So far, I have successfully managed to get the jobname, the info and the description, pretty easy. For the other parms, i'm able to get all the parms and to split them, but i don't know how to get rid of the garbage.

Here is my code:

```
var regex = "//([^\\s]*) JOB (\\([^)]*\\))?,?(\\'[^']*\\')?,?([^,]*[,|\\s|$])*";
Match match2 = Regex.Match(test5, regex,RegexOptions.Singleline);

string CarteJob2 = match2.Groups[0].Value;
string JobName2 = match2.Groups[1].Value;
string JobInfo2 = match2.Groups[2].Value;
string JobDesc2 = match2.Groups[3].Value;
IEnumerable<string> parms = match2.Groups[4].Captures.OfType<Capture>().Select(x => x.Value);
string JobParms2 = String.Join("|", parms);

Console.WriteLine(CarteJob2 + "|");
Console.WriteLine(JobName2 + "|");
Console.WriteLine(JobInfo2 + "|");
Console.WriteLine(JobDesc2 + "|");
Console.WriteLine(JobParms2 + "|");
```

The output I get is this one:

```
//JOBNAME0 JOB (BLABLABLA),'SOME TEXT',MSGCLASS=YES,ILIKE=POTATOES, GRMBL
//             IALSOLIKE=TOMATOES,      ANOTHER GARBAGE
//             FINALLY=BYE
//OTHER |
JOBNAME0|
(BLABLABLA)|
'SOME TEXT'|
MSGCLASS=YES,|ILIKE=POTATOES,| GRMBL
//             IALSOLIKE=TOMATOES,|      ANOTHER GARBAGE
//             FINALLY=BYE
//OTHER |
```

The output I would like to see is:

```
//JOBNAME0 JOB (BLABLABLA),'SOME TEXT',MSGCLASS=YES,ILIKE=POTATOES, GRMBL
//             IALSOLIKE=TOMATOES,      ANOTHER GARBAGE
//             FINALLY=BYE|
JOBNAME0|
(BLABLABLA)|
'SOME TEXT'|
MSGCLASS=YES|ILIKE=POTATOES|IALSOLIKE=TOMATOES|FINALLY=BYE|
```

Is there a way to get what I want ?

Comment: Have you considered doing this with two regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd try and do this with two `Regex` expressions.

The first one to get all the starting information from the beginning of the string - job name, info, description.

The second one to get all the parameters, which all seem to have a simple pattern of `<param name>=<param value>`.

The first `Regex` might look like this:

```
^//(?<job>[\d\w]+)[ ]+JOB[ ]+\((?<info>[\d\w]+)\),'(?<description>[\d\w ]+)'
```

I don't know if rules permit whitespaces to appear in the job name, info or description - adjust as needed. Also, I'm assuming this is the start of the file using the `^` char. Finally, this `Regex` has groups already defined, so getting values should be easier in C#.

The second `Regex` might be something like this:

```
(?<param>[\w\d]+)=(?<value>[\w\d]+)
```

Again, grouping is added to help get the parameter names and values.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

A small tip - you can use the `@` sign before a string in C# to make it easier to write such `Regex` patterns. For example:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(?<param>[\w\d]+)=(?<value>[\w\d]+)");
```